# how to insert data in an excel sheet into database(including blank spaces without editing them) using java

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, apache-poi

Java code to read all the cells in a sheet including blank cells in excel sheets and insert the same data into postgresql database without editing them.

I have already tried using apache-poi, missingcellpolicy, replacefunction, etc. But, it throws a nullpointerexception.

When I run my code to display the celltype of a cell in excel, it is not displaying any type for blankspaces and skips the cell completely.

Here is the code:

```
    package poiexcel;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.Format;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
//import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

//import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormat;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DateUtil;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class ReadExcel {

    public static final String SAMPLE_XLSX_FILE_PATH = "C:\\Raj's Documents\\Documents\\studentdata.xlsx";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {

        try {
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(SAMPLE_XLSX_FILE_PATH));// Read the spreadsheet that
                                                                                        // needs to be uploaded
            XSSFWorkbook myExcelBook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
            DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();

            for (Sheet myExcelsheet : myExcelBook) {
//              ArrayList<SheetDetails> details = new ArrayList<SheetDetails>();
//              for (Row row : myExcelsheet) {
                for (int i = 0; i < myExcelsheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows(); i++) {
                    Row row = myExcelsheet.getRow(i);
                    for (int j = 0; j < row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells(); j++) {
                        Cell cell = row.getCell(j);
                        CellType ct = cell.getCellType();
                        System.out.println(ct);
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
            myExcelBook.close();
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the output:

NUMERIC
STRING
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at poiexcel.ReadExcel.main(ReadExcel.java:52)

Comment: Could you show us *how* you tried it? I mean code...

Comment: I would love to read some sample code and see where you are getting a NPE. NPE happens for very specific reasons and usually there are obvious solutions.

Comment: BTW, have you tried OpenCSV?

Comment: @nabster No, i have not tried OpenCSV.

Comment: @deHaar I have uploaded the code related to the question

Comment: Could you show a sample from your workbook? Are all the data in the sheets of the same kind? I mean do all sheets have the same columns and do all cells have the same value types?

Comment: @deHaar No, every column in each of the sheet may have a different datatype but, data in each column is of same type.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *skips blankspaces*? Are empty cells skipped? That's possible due to the internal handling of rows and cells in apache-poi. Those cells might be regarded as *not present* but in Excel they are empty. You could iterate a little different: instead of the enhanced `for` loop use something like `for (int i = 0; i < row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells(); i++) { ... }`. Try that, might work...

Comment: In addition, the cell value can be obtained by several different methods depending on the type of data, like for example `cell.getDateCellValue()` or `cell.getNumericCellValue()`, while `String.valueOf(cell)` is not likely to give the desired result.

Comment: @deHaar just tried the for loop you have suggested but, when i tried to get the celltype and print it, it is showing me a null pointer exception when a blank cell occurs.

Comment: have posted the updated code and the output

Comment: That is the point... Check if `row.getCell(i)` is `null` and substitute the cell value with an empty `String` in that case. The cells are null because apache poi doesn't create instances of empty cells, wouldn't be very performant then...

Comment: The for loop advise solved my issue

Comment: You're welcome! I like issues getting resolved ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Under 'dependencies'in build.gradle (if using Gradle, otherwise find the matching dependency for Maven) file paste the dependency we want:

**compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-csv', version: '1.5'**

Create the following import:

```
import org.apache.commons.csv.*;
```

Parsing an excel csv file is then as easy as:

```
public Iterable<CSVRecord> parse(String csvPath) throws IOException {
 Reader in = new FileReader(csvPath);
 return CSVFormat.EXCEL.withFirstRecordAsHeader().parse(in);
}
```

EXCEL can be changed to DEFAULT if the csv files are plain text csv files.

We can then use the iterable list to get its values by id, column title or by enum, although these need to be defined. Then persist these values into the relevant database entity via the corresponding repository.